# Recommendation for 5 V, >2.5 A supply brick with 2.1 mm barrel jack (center positive) power supply

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc, radar

I purchased an [AWR1843BOOST](https://www.ti.com/tool/AWR1843BOOST#order-start-development) automotive radar sensor evaluation module.  The power supply must be purchased separately.

The specifications say I need a 5 V, >2.5 A supply brick with a 2.1 mm barrel jack (center positive).

I am unable to decide if it is a DC supply or AC and if 5 V, 3 A is enough or if 5 V, 5 A will be needed. How do I decide?

Comment: @winny I need to purchase power adapter, can you point to some example that fits this criteria. I am not an electrical guy.

Comment: It is 5VDC and the rating has to be >2.5A so either 3A or 5A is okay. You'll have to check the jack dimensions and polarity. Product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany It has cost me a lot of money to buy and wrong supply will burn it. It is requested that some product is recommended. I don't have money to purchase it again.

Comment: This is a product usage question. If documetation is unclear, ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Any power brick supplying 5VDC >2.5A would suffice. As Spehro said, either 3A or 5A, or any other one with an amperage >2.5A are fine.

Comment: 5.5 mm / 2.1 mm barrel jacks are fairly standard and should not be hard to find.

Comment: @Velvel The polarity must be correct, so not all power bricks have correct polarity.

Comment: We do not recommend specific products because an item that is readily available to me probably won't be available to you (and something I would buy would work on 120 VAC while I suspect you have 240 VAC available.)  And a product I recommend today may not be available next week.

Comment: @Justme Yes, as OP already stated in their question.

Comment: @PankajSejwal You might want to check out the [TI support forums](https://e2e.ti.com).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: @winny It is certainly helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's going to be DC (AC wouldn't have a 'positive') and 3 A should be enough if it's calling for a 2.5 A supply.